# Zfs on centos, can't create files?

Tags: centos, permissions, zfs

I'm running centos7... have 4 x 3tb hdd's, so I installed zfs as it looks like the best solution. I installed and setup via root, but the local user can't seem to write files / folders. And google won't yield any results as to why it wouldn't let different users have write permissions?
So my question is, how can I give the local user permission to write files on the pool?

Comment: You need to provide more information. Show some file permissions, paths and errors. Please update you question with adequate information.

Answer (score 6):

It's the same as any other mountable filesystem.  If you want users to be able to write to it then either chown/chgrp/chmod the mountpoint (after it has been mounted).

Better yet, create a subdirectory and give them write access to that.

Or, since this is ZFS, create them a zfs filesystem instead of just a sub-directory and grant access to that rather than to the entire pool.

e.g. if your zpool is called 'tank', you might do something like this:

```
zfs create tank/data
chgrp users /tank/data
chmod g+rwsx /tank/data
```

That will give all members of group 'users' read, write, and execute permissions on that directory.  the setgid bit will makes sure that all files & subdirectories created below /tank/data will be group 'users'.

If you want a more specific or detailed answer than that, you'll have to provide more information.

Comment: Thanx for the reply, I was away from my machine at the weekend - so I was googling the hell out of it with no avail... I'm a noob to linux as I setup a server for fileshares etc but have never dealt with groups etc. The owner and group for the file system is root, I changed the user group and added the permissions but still can't touch a file from the clip as user (not root). Does selinux get in the way of this at all or do I need to change the owner to the user as opposed to root?

Comment: impossible to say what the problem is without more information.  please edit your question and paste the text ([NOT an image](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text)) of your terminal session, showing at least the output of `ls -ld /path/to/your/zfs-filesystem` (or `stat ...` instead of `ls -ld ...`) and what happens when you try to write to or create a file.   the output of, e.g., `zfs get all tank/data` may also be useful.